# asp.net view state

Tags: asp.net, events, viewstate

Is it possible to get the value of the view state that ASP.NET writes in:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="..." />
```

, before the processing is done for the page, in C#, in one of the page events, such as

```
OnSaveStateComplete
```

If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer - no.

You could start playing with internal methods like `System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive` using Reflection but you have a very good chance that whatever you will build will stop working on the next .NET Framework update.

If you want to provide custom storage mechanism for ViewState you would implement [`PageStatePersister`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.aspx).

Comment: good hint though! I needed to try a different way of storing the viewstate data, ie. not by using HiddenFieldPageStatePersister; thanks!